# What is the "best practice" to fit a slickgrid into tight screen real estate?

Tags: slickgrid

We want to use slickgrid to overlay clunky and inflexible tables of data on hundreds of existing web pages built from business forms. Some tables are for display only, others are for user input/update. Thus, the real estate (and column/row counts) is set in concrete. To avoid conflict with the parent page styles, the grid is placed in an iframe. The approach has to take into account a caption bar, optional filter bar on inquiry-only tables, column header bar, and footing pager bar (only if required). Getting the ovarall height correct is the most difficult. It looks like the available tools are:

1. the geometry of the iframe
2. the geometry of the grid-container div in the iframe
3. options.rowHeight
4. options.headerRowHeight (if inquiry)
5. line-height css style
6. Font-size css style.

It seems that there is some mysterious arithmetic going on to calculate the number of rows displayed, the canvas size and the viewport size; and setting some of these items directly with script breaks the grid.
As a simple example, assume the height available is H pixels and must contain R rows of data. Are there any formulas or guidelines that give values to the items listed above? Or must we struggle with trial and error to make a good fit?

Comment: Do you already know the size you want to use? In my case I know the size I need (by viewport minus my menu) and I resize my grid in accordance